# ImageField in Django with Image from disk

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing an gallery application on Django and i have some question.

My goal is to show images from a path in the computer where my app is running.

For example all images I want to show are locate in "/usr/local/media/pictures"

There is no problem if I set my path "/usr/local/media/pictures" in MEDIA_ROOT and then show my image like this => (img src="/media/picture_1.jpg"/) where picture_1.jpg is in "/usr/local/media/pictures".

But now I want use some app which create thumbnail directly from a image (like solr-thumbnail).

My problem is solr-thumbnail create a thumbnail from a ImageField and I don't know how can I create an ImageField from a path.

I already search some documentation on ImageField and it look like that we need to declare ImageField on model, but i don't want store images in my databse. Because my user can delete/create image from his file explorer. There is no upload on my application.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit : my install of solr-thumbnail was bad. We can give just a file to solr-thumbnail for example : image = open(pathimage) then in tempalte : {% thumbnail image "200x200" crop="center" as im %} is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find instructions on the low-level api here

http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#low-level-api-examples

Alternatively, you can construct an instance of StaticFilesStorage and use it to pass ImageFile objects into your templates.

http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html#source

Comment: Hey thanks :) I will try it. I didn't look all documentation on solr-thumbnail because i was looking first ImageField ... my bad...

Comment: Don't listen to Aya. Django is a great framework, even if you're not using the database for anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no upload on my application.

In that case, there's not much point using an `ImageField`. Much of what distinguishes that type from a `CharField` is some extra code to make uploading easier.

I'd just use a `CharField` containing the full image path, if it's always going to be on the local machine.

TBH, it sounds like there's not much point using Django either. If you're creating an application which is designed to operate on local files, you might be better off doing a proper GUI with [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), or similar.

Comment: Yeah, but I want use some app which create thumbnail for me and they need image. But Thomas's answer looks good, i have to try.
EDIT : Thanks for your advice, i used Django because it looks fun to use, but i will look for wxPython.

Comment: @user2285361 you can also create a thumbnail using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) in about 3 lines of code.

Comment: Yeah i first create my thumbnail with PIL (image.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE)) but i want use solr-thumbnail for the cache.